# How can I access a GameObject variable in mono script from editor script?

Tags: unity, c#

In the mono script :

```
using UnityEngine;

public class TileTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefabPathOnTerrain;
```

Then in the editor script at the top :

```
private SerializedProperty prefabPathOnTerrain;
```

Then inside OnEnable()

```
private void OnEnable()
    {
        prefabPathOnTerrain = serializedObject.FindProperty("prefabPathOnTerrain");
    }
```

And then inside a method I want to use it as a GameObject :
And instead using CreatePrimitive to use Instantiate :
But doing :

```
GameObject go = Instantiate(prefabPathOnTerrain);
```

Will not work.

```
public void TerrainObjects(GameObject gameobject)
    {
        Terrain terrain = Terrain.activeTerrain;
        var cube = GameObject.Find(string.Format("Terrain_{0}_{1}", gameobject.transform.localPosition.x, gameobject.transform.localPosition.y));
        if (cube != null)
            return;

        if (cube == null)
        {
              GameObject go = Instantiate(prefabPathOnTerrain);              

            //cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        }

        cube.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(terrain.transform.localPosition.x + gameobject.transform.localPosition.x, 0, terrain.transform.localPosition.z + gameobject.transform.localPosition.y);
        cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(gameobject.transform.localScale.x, gameobject.transform.localScale.y, 1);
        cube.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("Terrain Map").transform;

        cube.name = string.Format("Terrain_{0}_{1}", gameobject.transform.localPosition.x, gameobject.transform.localPosition.y);
        cube.tag = "Terrain Map";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to [read the documentation for the data types you're using](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedProperty-objectReferenceValue.html).

A `SerializedProperty` could potentially hold any kind of data the Unity serializer supports. It's like backpack with different zippered pockets for different things you might want to carry. So if you want a particular kind of data out of it, you need to unzip the right pocket.

For a reference to a game object, that's the `.objectReferenceValue` pocket. So you want something like this:

```
var prefab = (GameObject)prefabPathOnTerrain.objectReferenceValue;
```

We have to cast it to the type we expect, because an `objectReferenceValue` could reference any `Object` type.

Then you can check whether the prefab is non-null and instantiate as normal.

Comment: I might make a new question because I've never heard of SerializedProperty before. What is that for?

Comment: @jhocking it's used for navigating and manipulating the exposed parameters on a script in a custom inspector or editor.